# Interpolation with order All function object not given as output

Tags: interpolation

I use mathematica10.4 and want to interpolate uneven data in 3 independent variable, (say r1, r2, r3). Because it is an unequally spaced data, I prefer interpolation order->All. But when I run the notebook I did not get any error message and also not any interpolating function object which mathematica always give out in the output cell indicating range of interpolation performed. After this, I tried with contourplot to plot by fixing one of the independent variable but got only empty plot.
Can any one help me to fix this problem?

I write the dataset I used for my interpolation so that people can work with it to fix what went wrong and also result of contourplot and mathematica script to perform all of the above.

I write the data below.Note that I write only part of dataset due to 30000 word limit.

```
{{{0.9, 0.26198, 0.645265}, 5.61944}, {{0.9, 0.121518, 0.842753}, 
  19.4776}, {{0.9, 0.202238, 1.0412}, 
  8.45447}, {{0.9, 0.28977, 1.14063}, 
  4.01734}, {{0.9, 0.383449, 1.24015}, 
  1.9101}, {{0.9, 0.479687, 1.33974}, 
  0.892754}, {{0.9, 0.577206, 1.43939}, 
  0.393146}, {{0.9, 0.675451, 1.53908}, 
  0.148149}, {{0.9, 0.774145, 1.63881}, 
  0.0319551}, {{0.9, 0.873136, 1.73857}, -0.018277}, {{0.9, 0.972334, 
   1.83836}, -0.0343042}, {{0.9, 1.07168, 
   1.93817}, -0.0337285}, {{0.9, 1.17114, 2.038}, -0.0268904}, {{0.9, 
   1.37029, 2.2377}, -0.0204067}, {{0.9, 1.56966, 
   2.43745}, -0.0358084}, {{0.9, 1.76917, 
   2.63724}, -0.0516075}, {{0.9, 1.96878, 
   2.83706}, -0.0615967}, {{0.9, 2.16846, 3.0369}, -0.0671804}, {{0.9,
    2.3682, 3.23676}, -0.0700648}, {{0.9, 2.56798, 
   3.43664}, -0.0714249}, {{0.9, 2.76778, 
   3.63653}, -0.0719729}, {{0.9, 2.96762, 
   3.83643}, -0.0721147}, {{0.9, 3.16748, 
   4.03635}, -0.0720732}, {{0.9, 3.36735, 
   4.23627}, -0.0719646}, {{0.9, 3.56724, 4.4362}, -0.0718441}, {{0.9,
    4.067, 4.93604}, -0.0716077}, {{0.9, 4.56682, 
   5.43591}, -0.0714806}, {{0.9, 5.56655, 
   6.43572}, -0.0713752}, {{0.9, 7.56623, 
   8.43547}, -0.0713164}, {{0.9, 9.56604, 10.4353}, -0.0713013}, {{1.,
    0.311151, 0.695115}, 3.74581}, {{1., 0.153719, 0.892396}, 
  13.4882}, {{1., 0.174484, 1.09067}, 
  10.7735}, {{1., 0.252689, 1.19002}, 
  5.26152}, {{1., 0.342432, 1.28947}, 
  2.44396}, {{1., 0.436654, 1.389}, 1.06291}, {{1., 0.532986, 1.4886},
   0.380761}, {{1., 0.630461, 1.58824}, 
  0.0426299}, {{1., 0.728621, 1.68793}, -0.121729}, {{1., 0.827222, 
   1.78765}, -0.196898}, {{1., 0.926123, 1.8874}, -0.22542}, {{1., 
   1.02524, 1.98718}, -0.229958}, {{1., 1.12451, 
   2.08698}, -0.222859}, {{1., 1.32338, 2.28663}, -0.199279}, {{1., 
   1.52255, 2.48633}, -0.187279}, {{1., 1.72191, 
   2.68608}, -0.193891}, {{1., 1.9214, 2.88587}, -0.202487}, {{1., 
   2.12099, 3.08568}, -0.208019}, {{1., 2.32065, 
   3.28551}, -0.211021}, {{1., 2.52036, 3.48537}, -0.212472}, {{1., 
   2.72012, 3.68524}, -0.213068}, {{1., 2.91991, 
   3.88512}, -0.213228}, {{1., 3.11972, 4.08501}, -0.213189}, {{1., 
   3.31956, 4.28492}, -0.213076}, {{1., 3.51942, 
   4.48483}, -0.21295}, {{1., 4.01912, 4.98464}, -0.2127}, {{1., 
   4.51889, 5.48449}, -0.212565}, {{1., 5.51855, 
   6.48425}, -0.212455}, {{1., 7.51815, 8.48395}, -0.212394}, {{1., 
   9.51792, 10.4838}, -0.212378}, {{1.1, 0.36055, 0.744986}, 
  2.52324}, {{1.1, 0.19363, 0.942076}, 
  9.11576}, {{1.1, 0.158079, 1.14018}, 
  12.6494}, {{1.1, 0.220765, 1.23946}, 
  6.89722}, {{1.1, 0.304114, 1.33885}, 
  3.30646}, {{1.1, 0.395264, 1.43832}, 
  1.46773}, {{1.1, 0.489879, 1.53786}, 
  0.547269}, {{1.1, 0.586285, 1.63746}, 
  0.0862641}, {{1.1, 0.683724, 1.7371}, -0.142045}, {{1.1, 0.781809, 
   1.83678}, -0.249794}, {{1.1, 0.880326, 1.9365}, -0.295692}, {{1.1, 
   0.979144, 2.03624}, -0.309103}, {{1.1, 1.07818, 
   2.13601}, -0.306011}, {{1.1, 1.2767, 2.3356}, -0.28121}, {{1.1, 
   1.47562, 2.53526}, -0.254799}, {{1.1, 1.6748, 
   2.73497}, -0.241748}, {{1.1, 1.87415, 2.93471}, -0.24289}, {{1.1, 
   2.07363, 3.13449}, -0.246786}, {{1.1, 2.2732, 
   3.3343}, -0.249417}, {{1.1, 2.47284, 3.53413}, -0.250769}, {{1.1, 
   2.67253, 3.73397}, -0.251327}, {{1.1, 2.87227, 
   3.93384}, -0.251463}, {{1.1, 3.07204, 4.13371}, -0.251404}, {{1.1, 
   3.27184, 4.3336}, -0.251275}, {{1.1, 3.47166, 
   4.53349}, -0.251135}, {{1.1, 3.97129, 5.03327}, -0.250865}, {{1.1, 
   4.47101, 5.53309}, -0.250723}, {{1.1, 5.47059, 
   6.53281}, -0.250608}, {{1.1, 7.4701, 8.53245}, -0.250546}, {{1.1, 
   9.46981, 10.5322}, -0.25053}, {{1.14, 0.380354, 0.764939}, 
  2.15673}, {{1.14, 0.210803, 0.961957}, 
  7.79884}, {{1.14, 0.155585, 1.16}, 
  12.9766}, {{1.14, 0.209979, 1.25925}, 
  7.60157}, {{1.14, 0.289786, 1.35861}, 
  3.73295}, {{1.14, 0.379289, 1.45806}, 
  1.68803}, {{1.14, 0.473016, 1.55758}, 
  0.654786}, {{1.14, 0.568884, 1.65716}, 
  0.134807}, {{1.14, 0.665968, 1.75678}, -0.124536}, {{1.14, 0.763805,
    1.85645}, -0.248751}, {{1.14, 0.862138, 
   1.95615}, -0.30327}, {{1.14, 0.960816, 
   2.05588}, -0.321125}, {{1.14, 1.05974, 
   2.15563}, -0.320259}, {{1.14, 1.2581, 2.3552}, -0.296487}, {{1.14, 
   1.45691, 2.55484}, -0.267785}, {{1.14, 1.65601, 
   2.75453}, -0.249302}, {{1.14, 1.8553, 2.95426}, -0.245109}, {{1.14,
    2.05473, 3.15403}, -0.247343}, {{1.14, 2.25425, 
   3.35382}, -0.249539}, {{1.14, 2.45386, 
   3.55364}, -0.250752}, {{1.14, 2.65353, 
   3.75348}, -0.251253}, {{1.14, 2.85324, 3.95333}, -0.25136}, {{1.14,
    3.05299, 4.1532}, -0.251283}, {{1.14, 3.25277, 
   4.35308}, -0.251141}, {{1.14, 3.45258, 
   4.55297}, -0.250993}, {{1.14, 3.95218, 
   5.05273}, -0.250713}, {{1.14, 4.45187, 
   5.55254}, -0.250566}, {{1.14, 5.45142, 
   6.55224}, -0.250449}, {{1.14, 7.45088, 
   8.55185}, -0.250386}, {{1.14, 9.45057, 10.5516}, -0.25037}, {{1.18,
    0.400177, 0.784894}, 1.84259}, {{1.18, 0.228436, 0.981844}, 
  6.67802}, {{1.18, 0.155642, 1.17982}, 
  12.9686}, {{1.18, 0.200612, 1.27904}, 
  8.28937}, {{1.18, 0.276163, 1.37838}, 
  4.19905}, {{1.18, 0.363712, 1.47781}, 
  1.93952}, {{1.18, 0.456407, 1.57731}, 
  0.783183}, {{1.18, 0.55166, 1.67686}, 
  0.197982}, {{1.18, 0.648343, 1.77647}, -0.0957836}, {{1.18, 
   0.745902, 1.87612}, -0.238728}, {{1.18, 0.844032, 
   1.97581}, -0.302572}, {{1.18, 0.942556, 
   2.07552}, -0.325563}, {{1.18, 1.04136, 
   2.17526}, -0.327264}, {{1.18, 1.23955, 
   2.37481}, -0.305048}, {{1.18, 1.43823, 
   2.57443}, -0.275201}, {{1.18, 1.63724, 2.7741}, -0.25302}, {{1.18, 
   1.83646, 2.97382}, -0.243383}, {{1.18, 2.03584, 
   3.17357}, -0.243085}, {{1.18, 2.23533, 
   3.37335}, -0.244565}, {{1.18, 2.4349, 3.57316}, -0.245546}, {{1.18,
    2.63453, 3.77299}, -0.245954}, {{1.18, 2.83422, 
   3.97283}, -0.246015}, {{1.18, 3.03395, 
   4.17269}, -0.245912}, {{1.18, 3.23371, 
   4.37256}, -0.245754}, {{1.18, 3.4335, 4.57245}, -0.245595}, {{1.18,
    3.93307, 5.0722}, -0.245302}, {{1.18, 4.43273, 
   5.57199}, -0.245151}, {{1.18, 5.43225, 
   6.57167}, -0.245032}, {{1.18, 7.43167, 
   8.57126}, -0.244968}, {{1.18, 9.43134, 10.571}, -0.244953}, {{1.2, 
   0.410095, 0.794872}, 1.70249}, {{1.2, 0.237393, 0.991788}, 
  6.18132}, {{1.2, 0.156631, 1.18973}, 
  12.8367}, {{1.2, 0.196526, 1.28894}, 
  8.61433}, {{1.2, 0.26965, 1.38827}, 
  4.44487}, {{1.2, 0.35609, 1.48768}, 
  2.07664}, {{1.2, 0.448206, 1.58717}, 
  0.854966}, {{1.2, 0.543119, 1.68672}, 
  0.234686}, {{1.2, 0.639583, 1.78632}, -0.0776623}, {{1.2, 0.736991, 
   1.88596}, -0.230534}, {{1.2, 0.835012, 1.98564}, -0.299624}, {{1.2,
    0.933452, 2.08535}, -0.325462}, {{1.2, 1.03219, 
   2.18508}, -0.328602}, {{1.2, 1.23028, 2.38462}, -0.307329}, {{1.2, 
   1.42891, 2.58423}, -0.27713}, {{1.2, 1.62787, 
   2.78389}, -0.253721}, {{1.2, 1.82706, 2.9836}, -0.241416}, {{1.2, 
   2.0264, 3.18335}, -0.239722}, {{1.2, 2.22587, 
   3.38312}, -0.240704}, {{1.2, 2.42542, 3.58292}, -0.241525}, {{1.2, 
   2.62504, 3.78274}, -0.24187}, {{1.2, 2.82472, 
   3.98258}, -0.241901}, {{1.2, 3.02443, 4.18244}, -0.241781}, {{1.2, 
   3.22419, 4.38231}, -0.241612}, {{1.2, 3.42397, 
   4.58219}, -0.241447}, {{1.2, 3.92352, 5.08193}, -0.241147}, {{1.2, 
   4.42317, 5.58172}, -0.240994}, {{1.2, 5.42267, 
   6.58139}, -0.240873}, {{1.2, 7.42207, 8.58096}, -0.24081}, {{1.2, 
   9.42172, 10.5807}, -0.240794}, {{1.22, 0.420017, 0.804851}, 
  1.5725}, {{1.22, 0.246431, 1.00173}, 
  5.72244}, {{1.22, 0.158248, 1.19965}, 
  12.625}, {{1.22, 0.192871, 1.29885}, 
  8.91895}, {{1.22, 0.263356, 1.39816}, 
  4.69774}, {{1.22, 0.348588, 1.49756}, 
  2.22117}, {{1.22, 0.44008, 1.59704}, 
  0.931724}, {{1.22, 0.534628, 1.69658}, 
  0.274664}, {{1.22, 0.63086, 1.79617}, -0.0572337}, {{1.22, 0.728108,
    1.8958}, -0.220557}, {{1.22, 0.826014, 
   1.99547}, -0.295184}, {{1.22, 0.924368, 
   2.09517}, -0.324041}, {{1.22, 1.02304, 2.1949}, -0.328735}, {{1.22,
    1.22104, 2.39443}, -0.308506}, {{1.22, 1.41959, 
   2.59402}, -0.278075}, {{1.22, 1.6185, 2.79368}, -0.253666}, {{1.22,
    1.81765, 2.99338}, -0.239171}, {{1.22, 2.01697, 
   3.19312}, -0.235787}, {{1.22, 2.21642, 
   3.39289}, -0.236163}, {{1.22, 2.41595, 
   3.59269}, -0.236788}, {{1.22, 2.61555, 3.7925}, -0.237056}, {{1.22,
    2.81522, 3.99234}, -0.23705}, {{1.22, 3.01492, 
   4.19219}, -0.236911}, {{1.22, 3.21466, 
   4.39205}, -0.236731}, {{1.22, 3.41444, 
   4.59193}, -0.236559}, {{1.22, 3.91397, 
   5.09166}, -0.236251}, {{1.22, 4.41361, 
   5.59144}, -0.236095}, {{1.22, 5.41309, 
   6.59111}, -0.235974}, {{1.22, 7.41247, 8.59067}, -0.23591}, {{1.22,
    9.41211, 10.5904}, -0.235894}, {{1.23464, 0.427281, 0.812155}, 
  1.48329}, {{1.23464, 0.253091, 1.00901}, 
  5.40874}, {{1.23464, 0.159817, 1.20691}, 
  12.4238}, {{1.23464, 0.190485, 1.30609}, 
  9.12548}, {{1.23464, 0.258897, 1.4054}, 
  4.8865}, {{1.23464, 0.343178, 1.50479}, 
  2.33154}, {{1.23464, 0.434182, 1.60426}, 
  0.991033}, {{1.23464, 0.528448, 1.70379}, 
  0.305954}, {{1.23464, 0.6245, 1.80338}, -0.040885}, {{1.23464, 
   0.721626, 1.903}, -0.212207}, {{1.23464, 0.819443, 
   2.00267}, -0.291324}, {{1.23464, 0.917731, 
   2.10236}, -0.32225}, {{1.23464, 1.01635, 
   2.20209}, -0.328156}, {{1.23464, 1.21427, 
   2.4016}, -0.308756}, {{1.23464, 1.41278, 
   2.6012}, -0.278221}, {{1.23464, 1.61166, 
   2.80085}, -0.253186}, {{1.23464, 1.81078, 
   3.00054}, -0.23733}, {{1.23464, 2.01008, 
   3.20028}, -0.232614}, {{1.23464, 2.2095, 
   3.40004}, -0.232495}, {{1.23464, 2.40902, 
   3.59983}, -0.232951}, {{1.23464, 2.60861, 
   3.79964}, -0.233153}, {{1.23464, 2.80826, 
   3.99948}, -0.233117}, {{1.23464, 3.00796, 
   4.19932}, -0.232962}, {{1.23464, 3.2077, 
   4.39919}, -0.232772}, {{1.23464, 3.40746, 
   4.59906}, -0.232595}, {{1.23464, 3.90698, 
   5.09879}, -0.232281}, {{1.23464, 4.40661, 
   5.59856}, -0.232123}, {{1.23464, 5.40608, 
   6.59822}, -0.232}, {{1.23464, 7.40544, 
   8.59777}, -0.232111}, {{1.23464, 9.40507, 
   10.5975}, -0.23192}, {{1.24, 0.429942, 0.814831}, 
  1.4518}, {{1.24, 0.25554, 1.01168}, 
  5.29825}, {{1.24, 0.160472, 1.20957}, 
  12.3412}, {{1.24, 0.189674, 1.30875}, 
  9.19712}, {{1.24, 0.257297, 1.40805}, 
  4.9563}, {{1.24, 0.341214, 1.50744}, 
  2.37293}, {{1.24, 0.432032, 1.60691}, 
  1.01342}, {{1.24, 0.526191, 1.70644}, 
  0.317841}, {{1.24, 0.622176, 1.80602}, -0.0346091}, {{1.24, 
   0.719255, 1.90564}, -0.208937}, {{1.24, 0.817039, 
   2.0053}, -0.289687}, {{1.24, 0.915302, 2.105}, -0.321448}, {{1.24, 
   1.0139, 2.20472}, -0.327812}, {{1.24, 1.2118, 
   2.40424}, -0.30873}, {{1.24, 1.41029, 2.60382}, -0.278171}, {{1.24,
    1.60915, 2.80347}, -0.252925}, {{1.24, 1.80826, 
   3.00316}, -0.236619}, {{1.24, 2.00755, 3.2029}, -0.231393}, {{1.24,
    2.20697, 3.40266}, -0.231091}, {{1.24, 2.40648, 
   3.60245}, -0.231479}, {{1.24, 2.60607, 
   3.80226}, -0.231654}, {{1.24, 2.80572, 
   4.00209}, -0.231607}, {{1.24, 3.00541, 
   4.20194}, -0.231445}, {{1.24, 3.20515, 4.4018}, -0.231252}, {{1.24,
    3.40491, 4.60167}, -0.231072}, {{1.24, 3.90442, 
   5.1014}, -0.230756}, {{1.24, 4.40405, 5.60117}, -0.230597}, {{1.24,
    5.40351, 6.60082}, -0.230474}, {{1.24, 7.40287, 
   8.60037}, -0.230585}, {{1.24, 9.4025, 10.6001}, -0.230569}, {{0.9,
    0.294305, 0.631177}, 4.48717}, {{0.9, 0.225235, 0.821139}, 
  7.10106}, {{0.9, 0.307971, 1.01496}, 
  3.51395}, {{0.9, 0.383281, 1.1127}, 
  1.93243}, {{0.9, 0.467933, 1.2108}, 
  0.98847}, {{0.9, 0.557691, 1.30919}, 
  0.46714}, {{0.9, 0.650444, 1.40781}, 
  0.190244}, {{0.9, 0.745074, 1.50661}, 
  0.0490608}, {{0.9, 0.840947, 1.60556}, -0.0183487}, {{0.9, 0.937683,
    1.70463}, -0.0463301}, {{0.9, 1.03504, 
   1.8038}, -0.0539057}, {{0.9, 1.13286, 1.90306}, -0.0522955}, {{0.9,
    1.23103, 2.00239}, -0.0482276}, {{0.9, 1.42812, 
   2.20124}, -0.0456827}, {{0.9, 1.62593, 
   2.40028}, -0.0526904}, {{0.9, 1.82422, 
   2.59947}, -0.0609064}, {{0.9, 2.02284, 
   2.79877}, -0.0666222}, {{0.9, 2.22171, 
   2.99817}, -0.0698881}, {{0.9, 2.42077, 
   3.19764}, -0.0715117}, {{0.9, 2.61997, 
   3.39717}, -0.0721844}, {{0.9, 2.81928, 
   3.59676}, -0.0723578}, {{0.9, 3.01869, 
   3.79638}, -0.0722983}, {{0.9, 3.21816, 
   3.99605}, -0.0721527}, {{0.9, 3.4177, 4.19575}, -0.0719937}, {{0.9,
    3.61729, 4.39547}, -0.0718514}, {{0.9, 4.11644, 
   4.89489}, -0.0716065}, {{0.9, 4.61578, 
   5.39441}, -0.0714814}, {{0.9, 5.6148, 6.39367}, -0.0713763}, {{0.9,
    7.61361, 8.39273}, -0.071317}, {{0.9, 9.61292, 
   10.3921}, -0.0713016}, {{1., 0.341753, 0.680592}, 
  3.03367}, {{1., 0.25217, 0.869718}, 
  5.51972}, {{1., 0.300641, 1.06283}, 
  3.53469}, {{1., 0.365763, 1.16027}, 
  2.01792}, {{1., 0.444049, 1.2581}, 
  0.994595}, {{1., 0.529695, 1.35625}, 
  0.393209}, {{1., 0.619657, 1.45466}, 
  0.0616115}, {{1., 0.712301, 1.55326}, -0.112547}, {{1., 0.806703, 
   1.65204}, -0.198188}, {{1., 0.902312, 1.75095}, -0.235274}, {{1., 
   0.998781, 1.84998}, -0.246054}, {{1., 1.09588, 
   1.94911}, -0.243355}, {{1., 1.19347, 2.04833}, -0.234728}, {{1., 
   1.38966, 2.24696}, -0.215866}, {{1., 1.5868, 
   2.44582}, -0.206687}, {{1., 1.78459, 2.64485}, -0.206836}, {{1., 
   1.98281, 2.84402}, -0.209601}, {{1., 2.18136, 
   3.0433}, -0.211808}, {{1., 2.38015, 3.24266}, -0.213016}, {{1., 
   2.57913, 3.4421}, -0.213504}, {{1., 2.77826, 
   3.6416}, -0.213585}, {{1., 2.9775, 3.84116}, -0.213473}, {{1., 
   3.17684, 4.04075}, -0.213294}, {{1., 3.37626, 
   4.24039}, -0.213113}, {{1., 3.57574, 4.44006}, -0.212957}, {{1., 
   4.07466, 4.93934}, -0.212695}, {{1., 4.57382, 
   5.43876}, -0.212564}, {{1., 5.5726, 6.43787}, -0.212455}, {{1., 
   7.57112, 8.43672}, -0.212394}, {{1., 9.57025, 
   10.436}, -0.212379}, {{1.1, 0.389839, 0.730086}, 
  2.05998}, {{1.1, 0.285392, 0.91845}, 
  4.13792}, {{1.1, 0.301535, 1.11089}, 
  3.43321}, {{1.1, 0.354486, 1.20803}, 
  2.13996}, {{1.1, 0.424732, 1.3056}, 
  1.10567}, {{1.1, 0.505109, 1.40352}, 
  0.442082}, {{1.1, 0.5915, 1.50171}, 
  0.056984}, {{1.1, 0.681623, 1.60012}, -0.152968}, {{1.1, 0.774175, 
   1.69872}, -0.258585}, {{1.1, 0.86838, 1.79747}, -0.307882}, {{1.1, 
   0.963754, 1.89636}, -0.324804}, {{1.1, 1.05998, 
   1.99536}, -0.324436}, {{1.1, 1.15685, 2.09445}, -0.315484}, {{1.1, 
   1.35195, 2.29287}, -0.2899}, {{1.1, 1.5483, 
   2.49154}, -0.268177}, {{1.1, 1.74549, 2.69041}, -0.256467}, {{1.1, 
   1.94324, 2.88943}, -0.252756}, {{1.1, 2.14142, 
   3.08858}, -0.252215}, {{1.1, 2.3399, 3.28783}, -0.25227}, {{1.1, 
   2.53862, 3.48717}, -0.252236}, {{1.1, 2.73753, 
   3.68659}, -0.25206}, {{1.1, 2.93659, 3.88606}, -0.251811}, {{1.1, 
   3.13577, 4.08558}, -0.251556}, {{1.1, 3.33504, 
   4.28515}, -0.251331}, {{1.1, 3.5344, 4.48475}, -0.251149}, {{1.1, 
   4.03307, 4.98391}, -0.250859}, {{1.1, 4.53204, 
   5.48321}, -0.25072}, {{1.1, 5.53053, 6.48215}, -0.250608}, {{1.1, 
   7.52871, 8.48077}, -0.250546}, {{1.1, 9.52766, 
   10.4799}, -0.25053}, {{1.14, 0.409202, 0.749903}, 
  1.76351}, {{1.14, 0.299987, 0.937981}, 
  3.65997}, {{1.14, 0.304202, 1.13016}, 
  3.34443}, {{1.14, 0.351869, 1.22719}, 
  2.17647}, {{1.14, 0.418431, 1.32466}, 
  1.1614}, {{1.14, 0.496345, 1.42248}, 
  0.48124}, {{1.14, 0.58106, 1.52058}, 
  0.0765305}, {{1.14, 0.670003, 1.61892}, -0.14802}, {{1.14, 0.761694,
    1.71745}, -0.264335}, {{1.14, 0.855249, 
   1.81614}, -0.318034}, {{1.14, 0.950118, 
   1.91496}, -0.337682}, {{1.14, 1.04594, 2.0139}, -0.338703}, {{1.14,
    1.14248, 2.11294}, -0.330203}, {{1.14, 1.33709, 
   2.31127}, -0.303602}, {{1.14, 1.53309, 
   2.50987}, -0.278895}, {{1.14, 1.73, 2.70867}, -0.262982}, {{1.14, 
   1.92755, 2.90764}, -0.255892}, {{1.14, 2.12556, 
   3.10673}, -0.253585}, {{1.14, 2.32391, 
   3.30594}, -0.252849}, {{1.14, 2.52252, 
   3.50524}, -0.252455}, {{1.14, 2.72133, 
   3.70461}, -0.252104}, {{1.14, 2.92031, 
   3.90405}, -0.251765}, {{1.14, 3.11941, 4.10354}, -0.25146}, {{1.14,
    3.31863, 4.30308}, -0.251208}, {{1.14, 3.51793, 
   4.50266}, -0.251011}, {{1.14, 4.01649, 
   5.00176}, -0.250706}, {{1.14, 4.51537, 
   5.50102}, -0.250563}, {{1.14, 5.51374, 
   6.49989}, -0.250449}, {{1.14, 7.51177, 
   8.49841}, -0.250386}, {{1.14, 9.51064, 
   10.4975}, -0.250371}, {{1.18, 0.428623, 0.769729}, 
  1.50769}, {{1.18, 0.315176, 0.95753}, 
  3.22543}, {{1.18, 0.308146, 1.14945}, 
  3.22824}, {{1.18, 0.350376, 1.24637}, 
  2.19886}, {{1.18, 0.413004, 1.34374}, 
  1.21707}, {{1.18, 0.488243, 1.44146}, 
  0.52643}, {{1.18, 0.57113, 1.53948}, 
  0.103851}, {{1.18, 0.658786, 1.63774}, -0.135093}, {{1.18, 0.749539,
    1.7362}, -0.261047}, {{1.18, 0.842388, 
   1.83483}, -0.320941}, {{1.18, 0.93671, 
   1.93359}, -0.343688}, {{1.18, 1.0321, 2.03248}, -0.346186}, {{1.18,
    1.12829, 2.13147}, -0.338308}, {{1.18, 1.32237, 
   2.32971}, -0.311244}, {{1.18, 1.51799, 
   2.52822}, -0.284405}, {{1.18, 1.71461, 
   2.72696}, -0.265072}, {{1.18, 1.91194, 
   2.92586}, -0.254594}, {{1.18, 2.10977, 
   3.12491}, -0.250166}, {{1.18, 2.30798, 
   3.32407}, -0.248401}, {{1.18, 2.50647, 
   3.52333}, -0.247528}, {{1.18, 2.70518, 
   3.72266}, -0.246945}, {{1.18, 2.90407, 
   3.92207}, -0.246489}, {{1.18, 3.1031, 4.12153}, -0.246122}, {{1.18,
    3.30225, 4.32104}, -0.245835}, {{1.18, 3.50149, 
   4.52059}, -0.245619}, {{1.18, 3.99994, 
   5.01963}, -0.245295}, {{1.18, 4.49873, 
   5.51884}, -0.245147}, {{1.18, 5.49697, 
   6.51763}, -0.245031}, {{1.18, 7.49485, 
   8.51607}, -0.244969}, {{1.18, 9.49363, 10.5151}, -0.244953}, {{1.2,
    0.438354, 0.779645}, 1.39306}, {{1.2, 0.322967, 0.967312}, 
  3.02403}, {{1.2, 0.310583, 1.15911}, 
  3.16073}, {{1.2, 0.350055, 1.25597}, 
  2.20381}, {{1.2, 0.410628, 1.35329}, 
  1.24381}, {{1.2, 0.484451, 1.45097}, 
  0.550452}, {{1.2, 0.566365, 1.54894}, 
  0.119747}, {{1.2, 0.653335, 1.64717}, -0.126252}, {{1.2, 0.743588, 
   1.74559}, -0.257077}, {{1.2, 0.836062, 1.84418}, -0.319897}, {{1.2,
    0.930095, 1.94292}, -0.344613}, {{1.2, 1.02526, 
   2.04178}, -0.347946}, {{1.2, 1.12126, 2.14074}, -0.340417}, {{1.2, 
   1.31506, 2.33893}, -0.313269}, {{1.2, 1.51048, 
   2.53741}, -0.285605}, {{1.2, 1.70695, 2.73611}, -0.264855}, {{1.2, 
   1.90417, 2.93499}, -0.252779}, {{1.2, 2.1019, 
   3.13401}, -0.247199}, {{1.2, 2.30003, 3.33314}, -0.244826}, {{1.2, 
   2.49846, 3.53238}, -0.243663}, {{1.2, 2.69712, 
   3.73169}, -0.242941}, {{1.2, 2.89597, 3.93108}, -0.242413}, {{1.2, 
   3.09496, 4.13052}, -0.242009}, {{1.2, 3.29407, 
   4.33002}, -0.241702}, {{1.2, 3.49329, 4.52956}, -0.241474}, {{1.2, 
   3.99167, 5.02857}, -0.24114}, {{1.2, 4.49042, 
   5.52776}, -0.240989}, {{1.2, 5.48859, 6.52651}, -0.240873}, {{1.2, 
   7.4864, 8.5249}, -0.24081}, {{1.2, 9.48513, 
   10.5239}, -0.240794}, {{1.22, 0.448096, 0.789563}, 
  1.28639}, {{1.22, 0.330877, 0.977098}, 
  2.83288}, {{1.22, 0.31332, 1.16877}, 
  3.08757}, {{1.22, 0.35002, 1.26558}, 
  2.20427}, {{1.22, 0.408484, 1.36284}, 
  1.26931}, {{1.22, 0.480837, 1.46048}, 
  0.575029}, {{1.22, 0.561737, 1.55841}, 
  0.136821}, {{1.22, 0.647992, 1.65659}, -0.1161}, {{1.22, 0.737725, 
   1.75498}, -0.251819}, {{1.22, 0.829809, 
   1.85354}, -0.317756}, {{1.22, 0.923541, 
   1.95225}, -0.344312}, {{1.22, 1.01847, 
   2.05108}, -0.348627}, {{1.22, 1.11428, 
   2.15002}, -0.341471}, {{1.22, 1.30779, 
   2.34817}, -0.314309}, {{1.22, 1.503, 2.54661}, -0.285948}, {{1.22, 
   1.69932, 2.74527}, -0.263466}, {{1.22, 1.89641, 
   2.94412}, -0.250381}, {{1.22, 2.09406, 
   3.14311}, -0.243621}, {{1.22, 2.29211, 
   3.34222}, -0.240582}, {{1.22, 2.49047, 
   3.54143}, -0.239094}, {{1.22, 2.68908, 
   3.74073}, -0.238213}, {{1.22, 2.88788, 3.9401}, -0.237606}, {{1.22,
    3.08683, 4.13953}, -0.237159}, {{1.22, 3.28591, 
   4.33901}, -0.23683}, {{1.22, 3.4851, 4.53854}, -0.23659}, {{1.22, 
   3.98342, 5.03752}, -0.236244}, {{1.22, 4.48211, 
   5.53668}, -0.236091}, {{1.22, 5.48022, 6.5354}, -0.235973}, {{1.22,
    7.47795, 8.53373}, -0.23591}, {{1.22, 9.47663, 
   10.5327}, -0.235894}, {{1.23464, 0.455233, 0.796824}, 
  1.21302}, {{1.23464, 0.336737, 0.984263}, 
  2.69931}, {{1.23464, 0.315509, 1.17585}, 
  3.03077}, {{1.23464, 0.350176, 1.27261}, 
  2.20165}, {{1.23464, 0.407063, 1.36984}, 
  1.28699}, {{1.23464, 0.478307, 1.46744}, 
  0.593212}, {{1.23464, 0.55844, 1.56535}, 
  0.149941}, {{1.23464, 0.644152, 1.6635}, -0.107944}, {{1.23464, 
   0.733491, 1.76186}, -0.247251}, {{1.23464, 0.82528, 
   1.8604}, -0.315491}, {{1.23464, 0.918784, 
   1.95908}, -0.343412}, {{1.23464, 1.01353, 
   2.05789}, -0.348518}, {{1.23464, 1.1092, 
   2.15681}, -0.341666}, {{1.23464, 1.30249, 
   2.35493}, -0.314528}, {{1.23464, 1.49754, 
   2.55334}, -0.285724}, {{1.23464, 1.69375, 
   2.75198}, -0.262401}, {{1.23464, 1.89075, 
   2.9508}, -0.247943}, {{1.23464, 2.08832, 
   3.14977}, -0.240696}, {{1.23464, 2.28632, 
   3.34887}, -0.237136}, {{1.23464, 2.48463, 
   3.54807}, -0.235387}, {{1.23464, 2.6832, 
   3.74735}, -0.234378}, {{1.23464, 2.88196, 
   3.9467}, -0.233706}, {{1.23464, 3.08089, 
   4.14612}, -0.233226}, {{1.23464, 3.27994, 
   4.34559}, -0.232878}, {{1.23464, 3.47911, 
   4.54511}, -0.232628}, {{1.23464, 3.97738, 
   5.04407}, -0.232274}, {{1.23464, 4.47604, 
   5.54321}, -0.232118}, {{1.23464, 5.4741, 
   6.5419}, -0.232}, {{1.23464, 7.47176, 
   8.54019}, -0.231936}, {{1.23464, 9.47042, 
   10.5391}, -0.23192}, {{1.24, 0.457849, 0.799484}, 
  1.18708}, {{1.24, 0.338897, 0.986888}, 
  2.65169}, {{1.24, 0.31635, 1.17844}, 
  3.00932}, {{1.24, 0.350271, 1.27519}, 
  2.20005}, {{1.24, 0.406574, 1.37241}, 
  1.29324}, {{1.24, 0.477405, 1.46999}, 
  0.59989}, {{1.24, 0.557251, 1.56789}, 
  0.154862}, {{1.24, 0.642761, 1.66603}, -0.104818}, {{1.24, 0.731952,
    1.76438}, -0.245439}, {{1.24, 0.82363, 
   1.86291}, -0.314528}, {{1.24, 0.91705, 
   1.96159}, -0.342955}, {{1.24, 1.01173, 
   2.06039}, -0.348359}, {{1.24, 1.10734, 2.1593}, -0.341628}, {{1.24,
    1.30055, 2.35741}, -0.314505}, {{1.24, 1.49555, 
   2.55581}, -0.285552}, {{1.24, 1.69171, 
   2.75444}, -0.261941}, {{1.24, 1.88868, 2.95325}, -0.24712}, {{1.24,
    2.08622, 3.15222}, -0.23957}, {{1.24, 2.2842, 
   3.3513}, -0.235813}, {{1.24, 2.4825, 3.55049}, -0.233963}, {{1.24, 
   2.68105, 3.74977}, -0.232905}, {{1.24, 2.8798, 
   3.94912}, -0.232208}, {{1.24, 3.07871, 
   4.14853}, -0.231715}, {{1.24, 3.27776, 4.348}, -0.231361}, {{1.24, 
   3.47691, 4.54751}, -0.231107}, {{1.24, 3.97517, 
   5.04647}, -0.230749}, {{1.24, 4.47382, 
   5.54561}, -0.230593}, {{1.24, 5.47185, 
   6.54428}, -0.230474}, {{1.24, 7.4695, 8.54256}, -0.23041}, {{1.24, 
   9.46814, 10.5415}, -0.230394}}
```

notebook script

```
SetDirectory[
  "/home/george/Varandas/work/o2h+/ooh+/adiabatic/pec/ci/cc-pVQZ/Cs/\
space.sym/2/spin/1/points"];
absraw = Import["gs_points.dat"];
Table[{{absraw[[i]][[1]], absraw[[i]][[2]], absraw[[i]][[3]]}, 
   absraw[[i]][[4]]}, {i, Length[absraw]}];
(*intrp=Interpolation[Table[{{absraw[[i]][[1]],absraw[[i]][[2]],\
absraw[[i]][[3]]},absraw[[i]][[4]]},{i,Length[absraw]}]]*)

Subscript[r, 1] = Table[absraw[[i]][[2]], {i, Length[absraw]}];
Subscript[r, 2] = 
  Table[Sqrt[
   0.25 absraw[[i]][[2]]^2 + absraw[[i]][[3]]^2 - 
    absraw[[i]][[2]] absraw[[i]][[3]] Cos[
      absraw[[i]][[1]] Degree]], {i, Length[absraw]}];
Subscript[r, 3] = 
  Table[Sqrt[
   0.25 absraw[[i]][[2]]^2 + absraw[[i]][[3]]^2 - 
    absraw[[i]][[2]] absraw[[i]][[
      3]] Cos[(180 - absraw[[i]][[1]]) Degree]], {i, 
    Length[absraw]}];
Table[{{Subscript[r, 1][[i]], Subscript[r, 2][[i]], 
   Subscript[r, 3][[i]]}, absraw[[i]][[4]] - (-149.9634043)}, {i, 
  Length[absraw]}]
intrp = ListInterpolation[
  Table[{{Subscript[r, 1][[i]], Subscript[r, 2][[i]], 
     Subscript[r, 3][[i]]}, absraw[[i]][[4]] - (-149.9634043)}, {i, 
    Length[absraw]}], InterpolationOrder -> All]
ContourPlot[intrp[2, x, y], {x, 0.122, 9.57}, {y, 0.45, 11.5}]
```

Explanation of script

I convert the original data (evenly spaced) in some other coordinates to r1, r2, r3 coordinates point by point for each value in the fourth column. After conversion, I attempted to interpolate data in r1, r2, r3 which are not evenly spaced.

Please any help is appreciated.

Comment: does `intrp` work? IOW does `intrp[2,1,1]` produce a numeric value?

Comment: I suggest simplifying your problem e.g. work with a smaller array of data, eliminate use of subscripts, avoid references to files that people won't have.  People do help, but you should try to make it easy for them.